# prevent cloudfront hosted images from being blocked in webmail

Tags: image, email, amazon-cloudfront, webmail

Cloudfront images going to webmail seem to be blocked on MobileMe and Yahoo mail. When we host our images on CF, they get blocked, like these:

http://d2x9dz1etb1m98.cloudfront.net/ugassets/deal/images/1/6/4b06b237/large.jpg

When we host directly in S3 they do not:

http://hrugassets-production.s3.amazonaws.com/ugassets/deal/images/8/9/ea3eb9d6/medium.jpg

Even when we've c-named the d2x9dz1etb1m98.cloudfront.net domain to our own domain it STILL doesn't work. I guess the webmail clients are aggressively trying to prevent spammy domains? It doesn't make sense though that they would resolve the c-name and still block.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: what does the html source look like?

Comment: It's a standard HTML email but any tags for images server from the above cloudfront bucket look like <img id='img1' class='main'></img> with src= stripped.

Comment: May be something to ask yahoo... perhaps bad privacy policy from cloudfront?

Comment: Have exactly the same problem, +1